# Razor IF/ELSE show HTML table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have two different tables that i'd like to display if a conditional token from my web-application is true otherwise show a different table. I'm not sure how to wrap my HTML properly inside razor

```
@if ("[HasRole:Administrators]" == "true") 
{
 <table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>MY 1st TABLE</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
}
else if ("[HasRole:Recruiter]" == "true") 
{
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>MY 2nd TABLE</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
    <table width="200" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>MY 1st TABLE</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Recruiter")) 
{
    <table width="200" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>MY 2nd TABLE</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
}
```